# Mysql single result from two tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination

Suppose I have two tables. table1 (16 rows) and table2 (20 rows).

I want to fetch results using paging suppose 10 rows per page.

Like firstly query returns 10 rows from table 1 then (6+4) total 10 rows from table1 and table2 like so.

Is it possible to achieve this in single mysql query.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please post what you have tried up to now?

Comment: I tried fetching result from first table when it starts returning empty data then i start fetching results from 2nd table keep in code the last page number from first table for getting record from second table start from page one again. I want to know is their any possibiliy of acheiving that in mysql single query.

Comment: why down voted and who

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **union** 
It does allow you to combine result from N different queries. 
[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) is a complete guide from mysql.

Let's say you have 2 tables named **table1** & **table2**

**table1** has column `id,name,birthday,created_at,age`

**table2** has column `id,firstname,lastname,created_at,salary`

Now let's say we want to select **id** and **name** from both the tables 
(there is no **name** column in **table2** we can combine **firstname** & **lastname** to treat it as name)

Here is what you need to do

```
data = Table1.find_by_sql("(select table1.id , table1.name from table1) UNION (select table2.id, CONCAT(table2.firstname,' ',table2.lastname) as name from table2) limit 10 offset 10")
```

Note: You can also use `where` clause in both of the queries to restrict what data you want

Comment: yeah you can change it as per your requirements it was to give you an idea how to do it